# copy HTML text using the clipboard javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, api, clipboard

I want to be able to copy images and HTML text and past it into my web application.

I am using the clipboard API to do so and my code works fine for images, for which I use:
[clipboard API read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read)

But for text, I am using this:
[clipboard API readText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText)
And I am only able to paste the raw text, not the HTML formatted text.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should already be possible in [Safari](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/) and [Chrome Canary](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5357049665814528), by simply calling `navigator.clipboard.write` with `text/html`, just like you currently do so with images via `image/png`.

(This was implemented in Chrome 86, and so will available in Stable Chrome by [October 6](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule))

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I also saw that here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=931839#c29