# TypeError: Failed to construct 'ClipboardItem': Failed to convert value to 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

I want to write text and html to the user clipboard. I am using the code snippet from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
        let data = [new ClipboardItem({ "text/plain": message })];
        navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function() {
            $.growl.notice({ message: ResourceService.getKey("CopyToClipboardSuccess"), location: "tc", title: "" });
        }, function() {
            $.growl.error({ message: ResourceService.getKey("CopyToClipboardError"), location: "tc", title: "" });
        });
    }
});
```

All I get is this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'ClipboardItem': Failed to convert value to 'Blob'.
```

Is there another way to copy text and HTML to the clipboard. What do I miss?

Comment: Can you give the type and content of the `message` variable? It seems that it can't be converted to a blob in the third line.

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? The Clipboard API is only a draft at the time of writing and only Chrome seems to support it fully (with `ClipboardItem`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard#Clipboard_availability

Comment: I am using the latest Chrome and message is a string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming your message is string type, [here is a demo code](https://www.javascripture.com/ClipboardItem)

your code would be

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
        const type = 'text/plain';
        const blob = new Blob([message], { type });
        let data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];
        navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function() {
            $.growl.notice({ message: ResourceService.getKey("CopyToClipboardSuccess"), location: "tc", title: "" });
        }, function() {
            $.growl.error({ message: ResourceService.getKey("CopyToClipboardError"), location: "tc", title: "" });
        });
    }
});
```

but Clipboard API and events are still working draft, I recommend using an alternatives like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Comment: And how would I add both - text and html? Like text would be "Banana" and HTML would be "<a href="http://banana.com">Banana</a>"

Comment: ClipboardItem currently only supports  text and image you can check your browsers supported type by running```setTimeout(async () => {
const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read();
console.log(clipboardItems[0].types);
}, 1000);```

Comment: I see, is there another possibility to achieve this task? clipboard.js also just copies text if I get it right?

Comment: I'm afraid not, HTML type is not supported by any system on OS level, so it's not possible, but if your text is valid HTML, softwares like word, excel can recognize it and interpret it as html

Comment: HTML is supported in Safari, and will be supported in Chrome 86. This is also described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63457395/7548103

Comment: Read clipboard-write permissions is deprecated https://github.com/w3c/permissions/pull/246/files